# Elm: Adding on eventhandler to a canvas generated by elm-graphics

Tags: graphics, elm

I am trying to add a `mousemove` eventlistener to the canvas generated by `elm-graphics`. I have absolutely no clue as to where I can add it. Do I use `toHtml` and then try to add the event handler to the `Html msg`.

Comment: it doesn't look like you can - could you achieve what you need to with svg instead?

Comment: It would be possible but due to certain constraints I would ideally use graphics

Comment: The final paragraph in the `elm-graphics` README suggests using SVG or Ports until a better API for canvas is established http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-graphics/1.0.1/